# Text analysis - "interpret" bag of words

Tags: machine-learning, text

I wanted to try to create a machine learning tarot card reader. Setting up a simulated draw of tarot cards and their associated meanings is straight-forward enough. However, the listed applications I see at the [scikit-learn documetnation page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) aren't that suitable. Perhaps a sentiment model would be the closest, but the sentiment/associated meaning of the cards could easily be part of the data structure. The "magic" so to speak is the interpretation of all the meanings together. There are a lot of permutations because different cards in different orders/positions/combinations would influence how a "human" would interpret the reading.

So I'm leaning towards an unsupervised machine learning approach; would also be more fun to let the model try novel interpretations. I'm just thinking out loud, but maybe a neural-network would get me there? Starting to sound like how Dalle-2 takes a text prompt and generates novel images.

In any event, for my desired application, anyway, I would like to feed an array of words, perhaps sentiment or "auspicious"/"ill-fortune"-weighted bag of words to a model. The model then takes those as inputs and outputs a grammatically-viable text output as its "reading." The user could also assign an overall topic, such as "love" or "career" or something to that effect.

### Question

I have laid out the bones of my desired application, but I'm unsure what the best open-source ML model would be suitable for this kind of project. Can anyone advise on what model would be most appropriate? Would prefer to work in python.

Comment: The broad task you're looking for is [language generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_generation).

Comment: @Erwan Helpful! Had not really encountered this field (or was aware of what it actually is anyway) Thaks.